# any method in coding auto update Android Apps, Not in Google play?

Tags: android

Any method to let the android Apps auto update?
except put into the Google play store?

i would like to update apps in coding? or any method?

i had found one with   CommonsWare Android Components
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-updater
CWAC Updater: App Updates, No Market Required`

unfortunately the project has been suspended, no more update,
so have any method like `swac-updater`?

Answer (score 2):

> Any method to let the android Apps auto update?

Apps cannot auto-update.

> i had found one with CommonsWare Android Components

That does not auto-update. It determines, for an app that is not installed via the Play Store, whether an update is available and downloads the update. The user still has to be involved in the update process.

> so have any method like swac-updater?

Step #1: Give your app some means of determining that an update is available, such as monitoring a defined URL on your Web site that will contain information about the latest edition of your app

Step #2: If you determine that an update is available, download it

Step #3: Once the update is downloaded, give the user the ability to perform the upgrade, such as via [starting the `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE).